# Vertically enumerated multi-column lists

Tags: lists, enumerate, multicol, tasks

I am looking for a list environment that places the elements forming a grid, (an array, a table...) and with the elements vertically numbered. This small detail has become to be a great pain for me. I have checked the `tasks`, `paralist`, `tablist`, `shortlst`, and `multienum` packages. But all of them handle the elements horizontally. On the other hand, the `enumerate + multicol` solution breaks the elements in an unacceptable way.

Ideally, I would like to have the tasks environment hacked to do this, but of course any ideas are welcome.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks,multicol}

\begin{document}
\def\q{A question}
\def\qq{A long question in this item}

\bf{Grilled (completely aligned) items but horizontally numbered:}
\begin{tasks}(3)
    \task \qq
    \task \q
    \task  \qq \dots \qq \dots
    \task \q
    \task \q
    \task \q
\end{tasks}

\bf{Vertically numbered but disordered items:}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
        \item \qq
        \item  \qq \dots \qq \dots
        \item \q
        \item \q
        \item \q
        \item \q
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can try to define a counter and use `paracol`.

Answer (score 1):

By using `paracol`, save items to sequence in vertical order and then read items in horizontal order

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_list_seq
\NewDocumentCommand {\myitem} { +m } {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_list_seq {#1}
}

\int_new:N \g_count_int
\int_new:N \g_row_int
\int_new:N \g_col_int
\int_new:N \g_ncol_int
\int_new:N \l_temp_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \calc_var: {
  \int_gset:Nn \g_count_int {\seq_count:N \g_list_seq}
  \int_gset:Nn \g_row_int {\fp_to_int:n {ceil(\g_count_int / \g_ncol_int)}}
  \int_gset:Nn \g_col_int {\fp_to_int:n {ceil(\g_count_int / \g_row_int)}}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \print_list: {
  \calc_var:
  \int_step_variable:nNn {\g_row_int} \l_row_tl {
    \int_step_variable:nNn {\g_col_int} \l_col_tl {
      \int_set:Nn \l_temp_int {(\l_col_tl - 1) * \g_row_int + \l_row_tl}
      \int_compare:nTF
        {
          \int_mod:nn {\l_col_tl - 1} {\g_ncol_int} = 0
        }
        {
          \switchcolumn[0]*
        }
        {
          \switchcolumn[\int_eval:n {\l_col_tl - 1}]
        }
      \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
        \item[\int_use:N \l_temp_int)]
          \seq_item:Nn \g_list_seq {(\l_col_tl - 1) * \g_row_int + \l_row_tl}
      \end{itemize}
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment {paralist} { m } {
  \begin{paracol}{#1}
    \seq_gclear:N \g_list_seq
    \int_gset:Nn \g_ncol_int {#1}
} {
  \print_list:
  \end{paracol}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\q{A question}
\def\qq{A long question in this item}
This is a list.
\begin{paralist}{3}
  \myitem{test1\\breakline}
  \myitem{test2}
  \myitem{test3}
  \myitem{test4}
\end{paralist}
This is another list
\begin{paralist}{3}
  \myitem{\qq}
  \myitem{\qq \dots \qq \dots \qq}
  \myitem{\q}
  \myitem{\q}
  \myitem{\q}
  \myitem{\q}
\end{paralist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP doesn't want horizontal order ;)

Comment: Yes, again a misunderstanding. The question is about horizontal and vertical alignment, and furthermore, vertical enumeration.

Comment: @e_moro sorry for that. But I have some new idea about the alignment. Left me some time to work about it.

Comment: @e_moro I have changed my answer, maybe it is what you want.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck, the code throws me the error:    Undefined control sequence.
\print_list: ->\calc_var: \int_step_variable:nNn {\g_row_int }\l_row_tl {\in...    and I am not able to debug it because I have not idea about expl3 syntax

Comment: @e_moro If you are not using TeX Live 2020, try to add `\usepackage{expl3}` before `\ExplSyntaxOn`

Comment: Great, that works! A couple of final suggestions: First, the algorithm should handle incomplete lists. That is, if you have a list of 5 items in a 3-column environment, a spurious sixth item appears. And second, it is not trivial to customize the \item declaration in your code to get alphabetical tags. This is absolutely necessary if you nest this environment with another one.

Comment: @e_moro I just provide a possible way that depend on `paracol` or/and `enumitem`, and implement a simplest version, more custom options means more code.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not want items in the same ‘row’ to be strictly aligned, you have the `listliketab` package which helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks,multicol}
\usepackage{listliketab, tabularx}

\begin{document}

\def\q{A question}
\def\qq{A long question in this item}

\storestyleof{enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
  \newcounter{tabenum}\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\refstepcounter{tabenum}\alph{tabenum})}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{0.3\linewidth}[t]{@{}LX}
\tabitem & \qq \\
\tabitem & \qq\dots \qq \dots
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{0.3\linewidth}[t]{@{}LX}
\tabitem & \q \\
\tabitem & \qq
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{0.3\linewidth}[t]{@{}LX}
\tabitem & \qq\dots \qq \dots \\
\tabitem & \q
\end{tabularx}
\end{listliketab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, yes I need rows "to be strictly aligned", like the tasks environment do. This is why I said "place the elements forming a grid". Sorry for the confusion at this point. Futhermore, I would like to maintain the simple list-like syntax if it is possible, in order to be able to easily add/remove items.

Comment: I'm afraid that you'd have to use tasks, with the values of the counter forced using the optional argument of \task (I mean using `\task[b)]` where you want it.  Unless someone is able to hack the code of the package…

Comment: Yes, I hope so. tasks or an equivalent environment. By the way, I am surprised that until now no one has had this need, or thought about it.